# Not calling controller on button click MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my example I'm unable to call a controller from a button click.
My button code is :

```
<button id="confirmsignup" name="confirmsignup" class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("RegisterUser", "Home")'" >Sign Up</button>
```

My Controller is HomeController.

My Action Method is :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult RegisterUser(UserInfo objUser)
    {

        int res= udaObj.RegisterUser(objUser);
    }
```

Comment: `location.href` won't post back. It redirects the current page to `/Home/RegisterUser` page with `HttpGet` status. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: On that button click, I need to hit that RegisterUser method for inserting my data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `location.href="someurl"` will issue a new GET request to that url, not a form post!

To submit the form (and it's data) to the HttpPost action method, Wrap your form elements inside a `form` tag and have the button submit it. Have the action attribute of form set to RegisterUser action method.

You can use the `Html.BeginForm` helper method to generate the form tag markup.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("RegisterUser","Home"))
{
  <!-- your other input form elements goes here -->

  <button id="confirmsignup" type="submit" 
                   name="confirmsignup" class="btn btn-success" >Sign Up</button>

}
```

Comment: Can I use one more like that(html.beginform...) in my cshtml page ? Because my another div contains another button which should hit LoginUser in the same controller.

Comment: Yes. you can have more than one form in the same view. But make sure they are not nested. Nested forms are invalid html

Comment: When I used two buttons 1 for login and 1 for registration, the registration is not redirecting whereas login is hitting controller.

Comment: I said 2 forms. not two buttons in same form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="confirmsignup" name="confirmsignup" class="btn btn-success" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("RegisterUser", "Home")'" >Sign Up</button>
```

the above code defines like has HTTP GET method .so you cann't call the Registeruser method when button click.

So you just use MVC form submit or jquery post to call that HTTP POST method 
Or else it consider has GET method.

Comment: Means, Can I use this method for both buttons with their concern action methods ?